# Getting error when trying to import p5-svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I successfully installed p5-svelte via terminal, the files show up in node_modules.  But when I try to import p5 into a component, I get an error message: [image]

I don't understand why its doing this. Here is my import code: `<script> import { page } from '$app/stores'; import P5 from 'p5-svelte';      </script>`

and here is a picture of what I installed: [image]

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Am missing something? Is this a bug??? I installed everything the correct way ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted my PC and everything works now... Turns out that if you install a dependency while npm is already running, the new install won't register...